# How to call Oracle stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, jpa, plsql, entitymanager

In the function you see here, I use EntityManager to retrieve data from functions created in packages in the database PL/SQL.That is, the data does not come from the table, but from the functions created in the packages.

```
@Override
public String getAccountInfo(String pinCode, String voen) throws SQLException {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select CUST_INFO_COURT.GET_ACCOUNT_INFO@DWHX('" + pinCode + "', '" + voen + "') from dual");
    List objectArray = q.getResultList();
    for (Object object : objectArray) {
        if(object != null) {
            Clob clob = (Clob) object;
            return clob.getSubString(1, (int) clob.length());
        }
    }
    return "Data Not Found.";
}
```

There is only one thing I want to do here. Now I only return values like String type `list`, but what I want is to return only single `entity` not list.

so that my response in the output like this:

```
[
{"account_number":"",
"account_type":null,
"open_date":"",
"currency":"",
"balance":0,
"closure_date":"",
"status":"CLOSE"
}
,
{"account_number":"",
"account_type":null,
"open_date":"",
"currency":"",
"balance":0,
"closure_date":"",
"status":"CLOSE"
},
{"account_number":"",
"account_type":null,"",
"currency":"",
"balance":0,
"closure_date":"",
"status":"CLOSE"
},
]
```

but i just want an object to return like this.

```
{
"account_number":"",
"account_type":null,"",
"currency":"",
"balance":0,
"closure_date":"",
"status":"CLOSE"
},
```

How can I change my method? I couldn't do anything using the singleResult() method.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Does the JSON com from the database function?

Comment: yes absolutely. I mean the json data is not from the table but from the function which is also in oracle. I just represent single result not list. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: But then I don't understand your question. You are looping over the result and just take the first result that obviously contains the full list

Comment: The return type of the method I want to do will be a pojo class and I will give the json data from the database to the properties of my pojo class, and at the end I will only return my pojo class.

Comment: I would suggest to use https://jooq.org That would it make mauch simpler

Comment: This method was written by someone else and now I need to fix it. @SimonMartinelli
And I explained what I want to do, I just don't know how to write it on the code side. I want to return only one object type json back using the getSingleResult() method.

Comment: But your function is returning the whole JSON, if I understand correctly

Comment: No my function is not returning json. It just returns normal data. I run this method in Rest Api because it is Json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239280/discussion-between-simon-martinelli-and-anar-mmmdov).